# How to update QAbstractItemModel view when a Data is updated

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qabstractitemmodel

I use the `Qt example for QAbstractItemModel` and I try to update an `Item` to a given `index`.

I tried to use `emit DataChanged`but it doesn't work, **the view is not updated**.

Here is an example:

**What I want**: When you click on the button, it will **update Data at index 0**, the `type` of the animal will be changed, it will become a **Lion**.

```
#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QStringList>
#include <qqmlcontext.h>
//![0]
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal(const QString &type, const QString &size);
//![0]

    QString type() const;
    QString size() const;

    void setType(QString q) {
        m_type = q;
    }

private:
    QString m_type;
    QString m_size;
//![1]
};

class AnimalModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    Q_INVOKABLE void test() ;
    void setName(const QString &name);
    enum AnimalRoles {
        TypeRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        SizeRole
    };

    AnimalModel(QObject *parent = 0);
//![1]
//!
//!
    void setContext(QQmlContext *ctx) {
        m_ctx = ctx;
    }

    void addAnimal(const Animal &animal);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;

protected:

private:
    QList<Animal> m_animals;
    QQmlContext*  m_ctx;

signals:
    void dataChanged(const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight);
//![2]
};
//![2]
```

*model.h*

```
#include "model.h"
#include "qDebug"
Animal::Animal(const QString &type, const QString &size)
    : m_type(type), m_size(size)
{
}

QString Animal::type() const
{
    return m_type;
}

QString Animal::size() const
{
    return m_size;
}




AnimalModel::AnimalModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}

void AnimalModel::addAnimal(const Animal &animal)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_animals << animal;
    endInsertRows();
}

void AnimalModel::test() {

  m_animals[0].setType("Lion");
  emit dataChanged(QModelIndex(),QModelIndex());

  //I also tried:
  QModelIndex topLeft = createIndex(0,0);
  emit dataChanged(topLeft, topLeft);


 }

int AnimalModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent) const {
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return m_animals.count();
}

QVariant AnimalModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const {
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_animals.count())
        return QVariant();

    const Animal &animal = m_animals[index.row()];
    if (role == TypeRole)
        return animal.type();
    else if (role == SizeRole)
        return animal.size();
    return QVariant();
}

//![0]
QHash<int, QByteArray> AnimalModel::roleNames() const {
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[TypeRole] = "type";
    roles[SizeRole] = "size";
    return roles;
}
//![0]
```

*model.cpp*

```
#include "model.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <qqmlengine.h>
#include <qqmlcontext.h>
#include <qqml.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickitem.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickview.h>

//![0]
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    AnimalModel model;
    model.addAnimal(Animal("Wolf", "Medium"));
    model.addAnimal(Animal("Polar bear", "Large"));
    model.addAnimal(Animal("Quoll", "Small"));

    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    QQmlContext *ctxt = view.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", &model);
//![0]

    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:view.qml"));


    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import QtQml.Models 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2


//![0]
ListView {
    width: 200; height: 250

    model: myModel
    delegate: Text { text: "Animal: " + type + ", " + size }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
        onClicked: {

        }
    }
    Button {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        width:50; height:50
        text:"click"
        onClicked: {
            myModel.test()
        }

    }

}
//![0]
```

*View.qml*

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Have you tried to implement the `dataChanged` signal with the documented signature: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged ?

Comment: Hello, what I tried first is to write something like `emit dataChanged(0,0)` in this case because the first `data` was updated. But dataChanged doesn't accept `int`, and I am a bit lost of what I should write here because I can't write something like `QModelIndex(0)`. This might be stupid stuff but I am really a newbie about such concepts.

Comment: I also tried `QModelIndex topLeft = createIndex(0,0);
      emit dataChanged(topLeft, topLeft);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't redefine signals in subclasses.

Remove the following lines (in model.h) and it should work as expected :

```
signals:
    void dataChanged(const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight);
```

Also this when calling `dataChanged()` you have to specify a valid [`QModelIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#QModelIndex). This is correct :

```
  // I also tried:
  QModelIndex topLeft = createIndex(0,0);
  emit dataChanged(topLeft, topLeft);
```

Comment: Or `emit QAbstractListModel::dataChanged(index(0), index(0)); `

Comment: beginResetModel();    endResetModel(); can help you

Answer (score 0):

You need create topLeft index and bottom right index and emit dataChanged. This update all model data in view.

```
QModelIndex topLeft = createIndex(0,0);
QModelIndex bottomRight = createIndex( rows count ,0);
emit dataChanged( topLeft, bottomRight );
```